# Kid's science fiction book from early-mid 1970s

Tags: story-identification

This is a book I read in about 1975 at the age of 9.  The book was targeted for that age or maybe a little older.  I recall it being comparable to the 'Danny Dunn' books, but I don't believe it was part of any series.

The main character is a boy of 10 or so, and there is also a girl of about the same age, and possibly a dog.  The boy's father is a scientist, and I think he goes missing, captured by aliens that are covertly investigating his research.  The boy and friends eventually save the day, of course, though I don't remember how.

The book was 8.5" x 11" sized, hardcover, and I believe the cover was purple, very purple.  There may or may not have been other stories in it.

Comment: This is for some reason making me think of *A Wrinkle In Time* although it's almost certainly not that.

Comment: @mithrandir Good guess, but definitely not that.